# What is the logic behind the trick used to prove the summation series of Sine of Angles in Arithmetic Progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

[image]

why does multiplying by $2sin(b/2)$ cancel out most of the terms,what is the intuition behind it?how does multiplying by it creates a chain of terms that get cancelled?

edit:1 I have attached an image about what I tried to simplify using $sin(d)$[image]

Comment: Makes more sense if you think at it as $\;\text{Im}\left(e^{ia}\left(1+e^{ib}+\dots+e^{i(n-1)b}\right)\right)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv,sorry but I am still  a student in learning phase,so I have not studied complex numbers yet

Comment: The trick is similar in a way to multiplying $\,1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1}\,$ by $\,1-x\,$ in order to get a telescoping sum which reduces to $\,1-x^n\,$ in the end. However, that similarity is not obvious without understanding the complex representation.

Comment: @dxiv,yes,I will be learning complex numbers  very soon,"1+x" expression helped me to get a logic,though i have used another method to find the sum,is it correct?

Comment: That looks correct, and can be further simplified to the other form using the sum-product identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the given example, it is observed that the original series can be
   converted into a **telescoping series**, which is a series whose
   *general term is expressible as the difference of two consecutive terms of some sequence*.

   This is achieved by multiplying<sup>҂</sup> it by $$2\sin\frac b2,$$ then
   applying the [product-to-sum
   identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)
   $$2\sin\theta\sin\phi=\cos(\theta-\phi)-\cos(\theta+\phi).$$ The
   resulting  **telescoping series** is
   $$\sum_{r=1}^n\left[\cos\left(a+\frac{(2r-3)b}2\right)-\cos\left(a+\frac{(2r-1)b}2\right)\right].$$
2. Next, the [method of differences](http://mathsathawthorn.pbworks.com/f/The+Method+of+Differences+pdf.pdf)
   is used to cancel out all the terms, except for the first and last
   ones, of this telescoping series.
3. Finally, the [sum-to-product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $$\cos\theta-\cos\phi=-2\sin\frac{\theta+\phi}2\sin\frac{\theta-\phi}2$$ is applied to express the result in terms of $\sin$ again.

---

<sup>҂</sup>**Answer to the OP's further question**:

Multiplying the series by $(2\sin b)$ instead of $(2\sin\frac b2)$ will result in the series $$\sum_{r=1}^n\left[\cos\left(a+(r-2)b\right)-\cos\left(a+rb\right)\right],$$ which isn't telescoping (refer the italicised text above); using the method of differences on this series will leave four instead of two terms.

Comment: but why only 2Sin(d/2) works,why can't 2Sin(d) work?I want to know how the one who actually derived it thought?please can you tell me?

Comment: I have attached an image,I tried it that way,can it be considered correct?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Great to see your attempt! Yes, procedurally, it does look correct.

Comment: thanks,your answer cleared my doubt