# Understanding Solution to Basic Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I think I'm not seeing the woods for the trees. In the recurrence relation below, how does this part

```
We know that T(0) = 1,
so, we assume n - k = 0
Thus, k = n
```

work please? I.e. why can we assume `n - k = 0`?

The recurrence relation for T(n) is given as

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1, if n > 0;
     = 1 , if n = 0
```

````
T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 -----------------(1)
T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 1 -----------------(2)
T(n-2) = T(n-3) + 1 -----------------(3)
Substituting (2) in (1), we get
T(n) = T(n-2) + 2 ------------------(4)
Substituting (3) in (4), we get
T(n) = T(n-3) + 3 ------------------(5)
If we continue this for k times, then
T(n) = T(n-k) + k -----------------(6)

We know that T(0) = 1,
so, we assume n - k = 0
Thus, k = n

By substituting the value of k in (6) we get
T(n) = T(n-n) + n
T(n) = T(0) + n
T(n) = 1 + n
```
````

Comment: They have argued that $T(n)=T(n-k)+k$ for any $n$ and any $k≤n$.  Taking the special case $k=n$ yields $T(n)=T(0)+n=1+n$.

Comment: They want to use $T(n)=T(\color{blue}{n-k})+\color{brown}k$ to find a simplified expression for $T(n)$.  Since it is known that $T(\color{blue}0)=1$, when $\color{blue}{n-k}=\color{blue}0$ it works to say $T(n)=T(\color{blue}0)+\color{brown}k=T(0)+\color{brown}n$ (since $\color{brown}k=\color{brown}n$ when $n-k=0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> T(n) = T(n-k) + k -----------------(6)
>
> We know that T(0) = 1,
> so, we assume n - k = 0
> Thus, k = n
> ```
>
> I think I'm not seeing the woods for the trees. why can we assume `n - k = 0`?

You're not missing the forest for the trees; *it doesn't make sense for the author to use the word “assume”* (to suppose without proof), which suggests that the step is tentative (it's not).

**All the author is doing is setting (“putting”) $k=n$**; this is valid, since equation $(6)$ applies for each $n\in\mathbb N$ and each $k\in\mathbb N.$ In so doing, the equation becomes: $$T(n)=T(0)+n$$$$=1+n.\tag7$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(7)$ gives $$T(n-1)=n,$$ so $$T(n)=n+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

We have

$$
\cases{
T_n-T_{n-1}=1\\
T_{n-1}-T_{n-2} = 1\\
\vdots\\
T_1-T_0 = 1
}
$$

After adding all rows we have

$$
T_n = n + T_0
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please? Maybe show what this addition would look like in process?

Comment: @RobinAndrews Cesareo is applying the [method of differences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216823/21813) on the telescoping series that results from summing the left-hand sides of the $n$ equations. (The right-hand sides sum to $n.$)